# Error in conversion of char to long

Tags: c

```
long int FinalValue;
char a,b,c,d;

a=0x1;
b=0x2;
c=0x3;
d=0x4;

FinalValue |=  (long)a;
FinalValue <<= 0x8;
FinalValue |=  (long)b;
FinalValue <<= 0x8;
FinalValue |=  (long)c;
FinalValue <<= 0x8;
FinalValue |=  (long)d;


Printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", a,b,c,d);
Printf("FinalValue = %ld"FinalValue);
```

**Output obtained:**
1 2 3 4
FinalValue = 0x05020304

**Expected Output:**
1 2 3 4
FinalValue = 0x01020304

When the above code is executed with different inputs (for a,b,c,d), the output obtained in MSB of final value is: 0x(a|d)bcd (in the above example 0x1 or with 0x4, to obtaine 0x5)

Why is the MSB byte is getting ORed with LSB byte?

Comment: Please post your *actual* code.  Copy-and-paste it; don't re-type it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First initialize `FinalValue` to `0`, uninitialized local (automatic) variables contain garbage.
2. change `Printf("FinalValue = %ld"FinalValue);` to `printf("FinalValue = %ld", FinalValue);` , add the comma.
3. What is `Printf` ? You probably meant `printf` .
4. You want output in hex ? Use `%lx` . `printf("FinalValue = %lx", FinalValue);`
5. Make `FinalValue` unsigned and then shift. Shifting of the signed bit of a signed number is implementation dependent.

**UPDATE**: added point 5

Comment: Change `%ld` to `%lx` as well.

Comment: If the OP doesn't expect commas between the single digits, then the print format should omit the commas too.  And if there's to be a space between the 4 and 'FinalValue', then that needs to be included in one of the two print formats.

Comment: @phoxis: Thanks..I had did all the things u had suggested, but still the problem persists.

Comment: @hemanth: can you post the actual code which you are compiling ? I cannot regenerate the problem with `FinalValue` initialized to `0` .

Comment: long int FinalValue;
was made as global variable which was initialized to zero only once in the Main function not in local function. So this problem was observed was not detected in 1st interaction, but in subsequent iterations it had there was problem because the LSB byte contained the varaible "d" from previous iteration.@phoxis Thanks a lot

Comment: @hemanth: be careful with globals, write comments i the file, how many and hat globals you use, their scope, intent to use, and the functions which will be accessing it/them.